# fix thsi please

Tags: python

I keep getting errors like this. It is a restaurant code, in which the menu is printed and orders are taken but error is in writing the order and cost in a file text,

I have tried to make a menu in form of  dictionary, but can't write  the data in text file

```
class restaurant():
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ""
    self.menu = {}
    self.order = []
    self.bill = 0
  def print_menu(self):
    print "MENU CARD"
    self.menu = {'BBQ Grill':'50','Chicken Gollati':'80','French fries':'60',
            'Hara Bara Kabab':'90','Makani Special Dum Biriyani':'100',
             'Egg Jumbo Sandwich':'120','Roasted Prawn   Salad':'90',
              'Parathas':'80','Turkish Barbeque Plate':'100'}
    for item in self.menu:
      print item,"-",self.menu[item]
  def takeorder(self):
    f1 = open("billlog.txt","w")
    print "What would you like to order?"
    ans = "y"
    while ans == "y":
      food = raw_input("enter order - ")
      self.bill += int(self.menu[food])
      ans = raw_input("go on?(y/n): ")
      f1.write(food)
      f1.write("\t\t")
      f1.write(self.bill)
      print food,"\t\t\t",self.bill
    f1.close()
  def readfilebilllogs(self):
    f1 = open("billlog.txt","r")
    f1.read()
    f1.close()
r = restaurant()
r.print_menu()
r.takeorder()
r.readfilebilllogs()
```

Comment: Certainly the code is not correct when there is an error. The error is also clear: you are referencing a variable before assigning a value. You probably want `self.bill`...

Comment: Please add the error message as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple errors. Try this it should work. I tried on python3 and modified for python2.7 so there could be some syntax error. I've explained the errors in comment

```
class restaurant():
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ""
    self.menu = {}
    self.order = []
    self.bill = 0
  def print_menu(self):
    print "MENU CARD"
##This should be self.menu instead of just menu. If you use just menu it's a local variable which can't be used from other function
    self.menu = {'BBQ Grill':'50','Chicken Gollati':'80','French fries':'60',
            'Hara Bara Kabab':'90','Makani Special Dum Biriyani':'100',
             'Egg Jumbo Sandwich':'120','Roasted Prawn   Salad':'90',
              'Parathas':'80','Turkish Barbeque Plate':'100'}
#Again self.menu
    for item in self.menu:
      print item,"-",self.menu[item]
  def has_item(self):
    name = raw_input("Enter name of costumer: ")
    food = raw_input("Enter order: ")
    for i in self.menu:
      if i == food:
        print "Yes"
      else:
        print "No"

# The first parameter is always instance of the class (self).
  def takeorder(self):
    print "What would you like to order?"
    ans = "y"
    while ans == "y":
      food = raw_input("enter order - ")
# Instead of bill it should be self.bill
#Convert string value of cost to int while adding
      self.bill += int(self.menu[food])
      ans = raw_input("go on?(y/n): ")
    print self.bill
r = restaurant()
r.print_menu()
r.takeorder()
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of errors in there:

- `Turkish Barbeque Plate'` this is missing an apostrophe in the beginning.
- You defined your fields in the constructor so to use them in other methods inside the class, you need to prefix with `self`. This is why you need to pass self to all other methods. Also takeorder method needs to be passed self not print_menu.
- Your menu items' values are of type str while in this line `bill += menu[food]` you are adding str to bill which is an int. This is not going to work. Either change values to int or change this line to `bill += int(menu[food])`

Answer (score 0):

Change line:

```
bill += menu[food]
```

into:

```
self.bill += menu[food]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue  I can see is that in your `menu` variable there is an apostrophe missing before Turkish Barbeque Plate which will break your dictionary.

Secondly, you're referring to bill before its created.

I've fixed up a few things and the following should work.

```
class restaurant():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.order = []
        self.bill = 0
        self.menu = {'BBQ Grill':50,
                     'Chicken Gollati':80,
                     'French fries':60,
                     'Hara Bara Kabab':90,
                     'Makani Special Dum Biriyani':100,
                     'Egg Jumbo Sandwich':120,
                     'Roasted Prawn Salad':90,
                     'Parathas':80,
                     'Turkish Barbeque Plate':100}

    def print_menu(self):
        print ("MENU CARD")
        for item in self.menu:
            print '{} - {}'.format(item, self.menu[item])

    def has_item(self):
        name = raw_input("Enter name of customer: ")
        food = raw_input("Enter order: ")
        for item in self.menu():
            if item == food:
                print "Yes"
            else:
                print "No"

    def take_order(self):
        print "What would you like to order? "
        response = 'yes'
        while response.lower() == 'yes':     #.lower() to remove caps from response
            food = raw_input("Enter Order: ")
            self.bill += self.menu[food]
            response = raw_input("Go on? (Yes or No): ")
        print self.bill

r = restaurant()
r.print_menu() 
r.take_order()
```